# Unpinning accepted answer from top of list of answers on G&FH SE

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

[Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers) has been implemented for Stack Overflow.

Would we like to see the same to be done for G&FH SE?

---

This discussion feeds into [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369914/215590) to [Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568) where our preference is yet to be recorded.

Answer (score 3):

I see advantages of both and don't feel strongly either way.

StackOverflow usually has more answers per question and often the accepted answer does not have the most votes. So their decision to unpin often moves the accepted answer down.

I guess it depends who you trust more: the asker or the general populace.